# I'm trying to find an invisible field to fill in using Capybara, but nothing I am doing seems to work

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, rubygems, capybara

I am currently trying to fill in the Google sign in form using Capybara, but I am having the hardest time getting it to find the hidden field to fill in.

Here is the HTML for the field I am trying to fill in.

[image]

Here is the test code

```
require "rails_helper.rb"

RSpec.describe "Sign in page" do
    it 'displays the page intention' do
        visit('/mars')
        expect(page).to have_content 'Sign in with Google'
    end
    it 'fills in user information' do
       find(:xpath, '//*[@id="identifierId"]', visible: false)
    end
end
```

And this is the error I am getting.[image]

Comment: Try find by using ID 'indentifierId'

Comment: @bhupathituraga that gives me the error 'Unable to find id "identifierId"'

Comment: First switch to active element then find using I'd

Comment: I am not familiar with the switch command, but I added 'switch_to_frame('identifierId')' before the find command and I am still getting the same error @bhupathituraga

Comment: Its not frame its just active element `driver.switch_to.active_element()`

Comment: @bhupathituraga any idea how to fix "undefined local variable or method `driver'"?

Comment: You should not need to use driver specific methods for this, and 99.99% of the time if you find yourself typing `driver.anything` when using Capybara you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Please add your HTML and error as text and not images. Images are not compatible with clipboards, screen-readers and search engines. Would you repair this promptly, so we can save this question from closure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you shouldn't be attempting to fill in a hidden field, you should be interacting with the visible elements like a user would have to.  In this case, it may mean needing to click on another element first to trigger the email input to change to being active. Something like

```
first('form div[jscontroller]').click
fill_in('identifierId', with: email)
```

should work for the google login page.

Note: also you should be preferring CSS over XPath for finding elements whenever possible, since it will be faster, easier to read, and can't unintentionally break element scoping (`//` vs `.//` in XPath - see https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#beware-the-xpath--trap)

Update: Additionally all the `it` blocks are completely independent, with a browser reset in between, so you need to visit the desired page for each one (if all the `it` blocks in the `describe` require visiting the same page you could put the visit in a `before` block.

Note: this all assumes you are actually using the Selenium driver for this test, as the question tags imply.

Comment: Yeah I am using the Selenium driver for this test. I still am having a tough time trying to find the correct visible css. Everything I try gives me the error 'Capybara::ExpectationNotMet: expected to find visible css'.

Comment: @throwthedays Sleep a few seconds after visiting the page and then call `save_and_open_screenshot` and add that image to your question.  You can also pause the test (byebug, pry, sleep, etc) and look at the browser to see what the current page state actually is - if the code I posted doesn't work then it sounds like you're not actually on the google login page.

Comment: @throwthedays One other thing I just noticed -- your test doesn't actually visit anywhere -  Is the visit in a before block?

Comment: The visit('/mars') goes to the page. I specify that location in a routes.db file. Also I figured out that between the two scenarios the page does not refresh correctly. No matter how long I make it sleep, it does not reload.

Comment: @throwthedays But you don't have `visit('/mars')` in your `it 'fills in user information' do` test -- each `it` is completely separate from each other -- a screenshot (or just looking at the browser) would have shown you that it's not actually on the page because the browser gets reset to `about:blank` between every test.

Comment: In your experience, would you suggest to make one long `it` block so that it only loads the page once. Or would it be better to have multiple `it` blocks that will load a new page every time. I feel like the latter example will be very redundant once I am testing within the app.

Comment: @throwthedays When writing feature tests you should write something that tests the feature -- If that feature is "logging in" then it should do everything necessary to login - if the feature is "buy a product from the store" then the `it` block would be longer and may include adding the product to the cart and checking out.  The rule of one expectation per test doesn't apply to feature tests.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173358/discussion-between-throwthedays-and-thomas-walpole).